# how to install packages within conda env

Tags: python-3.x, conda, miniconda

i created an environment using conda and then added a package to it but it does not show up in list of installed packages when i do conda list. I did conda list because my code is not able to import the package i installed. it is hapenning for other package but this example shows pandas:

```
(myenv) manishshukla@manishs-mbp ForecastModel % conda create -n testenv

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /Users/manishshukla/.conda/envs/.conda_envs_dir_test
  uid: 501
  gid: 20

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 501:20 /Users/manishshukla/.conda/envs/.conda_envs_dir_test

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.


(myenv) manishshukla@manishs-mbp ForecastModel % sudo conda create -n testenv1
Password:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/manishshukla/miniconda3/envs/testenv1



Proceed ([y]/n)? Y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate testenv1
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(myenv) manishshukla@manishs-mbp ForecastModel % conda activate testenv1
(testenv1) manishshukla@manishs-mbp ForecastModel % conda install pandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /Users/manishshukla/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt
  uid: 501
  gid: 20

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 501:20 /Users/manishshukla/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.


(testenv1) manishshukla@manishs-mbp ForecastModel % sudo conda install pandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

(testenv1) manishshukla@manishs-mbp ForecastModel % python3
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>>>
```

i get error below:

```
Dataprep.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Any pointers will be helpful. this is a macbook if that matters and i installed miniconda.

Comment: What are you using and how are you using it to install these packages? Also, are you sure the environment is enabled when you run the install Command?

Answer (score 1):

Try without sudo. In general you do not need sudo to install packages with conda

**Update after question was updated**

It seems there is a problem with permissions. Have you tried following the advise conda is giving you instead of using sudo?

Try `sudo chown 501:20 /Users/manishshukla/.conda/envs` before creating the environment.
Is it possible that you installed conda with sudo? If you did, I would suggest to reinstall it without using sudo.

Comment: Agreed. Also the `/Users/manishshukla/miniconda3/` location indicates that Miniconda is installed locally, so again, no need for sudo.

Comment: wel... tried without sudo and i was getting error :(

Comment: please post all the commands you enter, from environment creation till first pandas import